# when i upload image to save in database with foriegn key 'username' i get an error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

***models.py***

```
class UploadImg_Model(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users_files/uplaods/images')
    uploaded_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

***views.py***

```
def UploadImg(request, usrnm):
    Data = UploadImg_Model()
    Fields = UploadImg_Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
    #print('FILES     :     ', request.FILES)
    #print('POST      :     ', request.POST)
    if Fields.is_valid():
        Data.Image = Fields.cleaned_data['Image']
        #print('IMAGE    :    ', Data.Image)
        Data.save()
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'User': usrnm})
    return render(request, 'upload_images.html', {'User': usrnm,
                                                'Form': UploadImg_Form})
```

***ERROR***

> IntegrityError at /oneapp/myaccount/AnonymousUser/upload/
>
> NOT NULL constraint failed: oneapp_uploadimg_model.username_id

Comment: i tried log in and upload image but same error: IntegrityError at /oneapp/myaccount/trk994/upload/

NOT NULL constraint failed: oneapp_uploadimg_model.username_id

Comment: you are not giving username (ForeignKey field)

Comment: How????????????

Comment: Data.username = usrnm ????????

Comment: yes...usrnm  must be instance of "User" model.

Comment: Cannot assign "'trk994'": "UploadImg_Model.username" must be a "User" instance. ?????

Comment: yes..username must be "User" instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing username (it's a not null field). it must be a "User" model instance.
like if you want to save "trk994" as username. Do this.

```
if Fields.is_valid():
        user_instance = User.objects.get(username="trk994")
        Data.username = user_instance 
        Data.Image = Fields.cleaned_data['Image']
        #print('IMAGE    :    ', Data.Image)
        Data.save()
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'User': usrnm})
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro